# Calling FQL queries from the iPhone fbconnect libraries

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, fbconnect

I started developing an iPhone application in June 2010 that used the Facebook APIs extensively. I logged in and got a `FBSession` which contains the logged in user's profile id, etc. I then used the `FBRequest` class to make many calls using the [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) to get data.

How do I call FQL queries from the latest Facebook Connect APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid=4", @"query",
                                  nil];

   [_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate: self];
```